# Intro HTML & CSS unable to properly center a gallery heading inside div

Tags: html, css

Obligatory: "I'm very new to this so please bear this in mind" disclaimer.

I am working on a project for an online bookstore. It's still very bare bones.

I can't seem to get the header for the gallery centered over the images. I have tried margin:auto, text-align, and absolute positioning. The last one seems to stop moving after I surpass 30 as a setting for left and/or top.

Extra: I wasn't able to get the image headers (h3) centered over the images either so I kind of gave up on those, but if anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #000000;
}

.searchbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #6e4c8a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

#search {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 750px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
  clear: both;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #d8cee0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

aside section li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-family: 'arial', verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.gallery.item {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 198px;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="volga, project, books, bookstore, online">
  <meta name="description" content="Online Bookstore">
  <title>Volga: Books That You Need In Your Life</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="volgastyles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="font-size: 45pt;font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight: lighter;margin: 15px;">VOLGA</h1>
  <div class="searchbox">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for books" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper" style="background-color:ghostwhite">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Nonfiction</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Travel</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Science Fiction</a></li>
          <li><a href="artemis.html">Artemis</a></li>
          <li><a href="sleeping-giants.html">Sleeping Giants</a></li>
          <li><a href="left-hand-of-darkness.html">The Left Hand of Darkness</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <aside>
      <section class="listicles">
        <ol>
          <li>Top 10</li>
          <li>New Releases</li>
          <li>Coming Soon</li>
          <li>Bestsellers</li>
          <li>Award-Winning</li>
          <li>Steals</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <section class="curated">
      <h2 style="margin:auto"><i>Curated Selections</i></h2>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Photography Guides</h3>
          <a href="https://www.digitalcameraworld.com/features/best-photography-books">
            <img src="unsplash/unsplash-cameras.jpg" title="The best photography books for beginners and pros in 2019" alt="Cameras"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Learn to DIY</h3>
          <a href="http://blog.partswarehouse.com/11-of-the-best-diy-books-youll-ever-read/">
            <img src="unsplash/unsplash-frames.jpg" title="11 of the Best DIY Books You’ll Ever Read" alt="Frames"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Immerse Yourself</h3>
          <a href="https://www.digitalcameraworld.com/features/best-photography-books">
            <img src="unsplash/unsplash-space.jpg" title="The best photography books for beginners and pros in 2019" alt="Cameras"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Fall in Love</h3>
          <a href="http://blog.partswarehouse.com/11-of-the-best-diy-books-youll-ever-read/">
            <img src="unsplash/unsplash-love.jpg" title="11 of the Best DIY Books You’ll Ever Read" alt="Frames"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy; UW-Parkside CSCI 220</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
````

Comment: Bit confused. you want to set at the center of this div -> "curated" ?

Comment: Can you add screenshot.

Comment: Please give me clear picture. what do you want?

Comment: i have made changes. Please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/bk0yxr3q/7/

Comment: Sorry. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like for me. It's more or less the same results whether I try margin:auto, text-align:center, etc.
https://snipboard.io/0Sy1qj.jpg

Comment: Please don't use float property. if you are using flex. Because there is no need of float.I will make changes and update you soon.

Comment: Please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/scetnj8d/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying is the H2 element with the text value "Curated Selections" won't center.  What's causing the issue is you're floating the value for your aside element without making its position absolute.  So if you set its position absolute then set the text-align for your H2 to center, it'll align centrally in your wrapper div.

```
aside {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below style does the work, with your existing code. It centers your heading text.

`h3{
  text-align:center;
}`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have made changes into css. Please check it. I removed float property in all the classes. Hope you will see changes. And if any changes you want please let me know.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #000000;
}


.searchbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #6e4c8a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

#search {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
  clear: both;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #d8cee0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.partition{
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

aside section li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-family: 'arial', verdana, sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery.item {
  padding: 30px 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 45%;
}

img {
 width:100%; 
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.curated{
  padding-left:20px;
      width: 80%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.gallery h3{
  text-align: center;
}
.curated h2{text-align:center}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 45pt;font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight: lighter;margin: 15px;">VOLGA</h1>
<div class="searchbox">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for books" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:ghostwhite">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Nonfiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Science Fiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="artemis.html">Artemis</a></li>
        <li><a href="sleeping-giants.html">Sleeping Giants</a></li>
        <li><a href="left-hand-of-darkness.html">The Left Hand of Darkness</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="partition">
    <aside>
      <section class="listicles">
        <ol>
          <li>Top 10</li>
          <li>New Releases</li>
          <li>Coming Soon</li>
          <li>Bestsellers</li>
          <li>Award-Winning</li>
          <li>Steals</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <section class="curated">
      <h2 style="margin:auto"><i>Curated Selections</i></h2>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Photography Guides</h3>
          <a href="https://www.digitalcameraworld.com/features/best-photography-books">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ff00ff/000000.png" title="The best photography books for beginners and pros in 2019" alt="Cameras"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Learn to DIY</h3>
          <a href="http://blog.partswarehouse.com/11-of-the-best-diy-books-youll-ever-read/">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/0000ff/000000.png" title="11 of the Best DIY Books You’ll Ever Read" alt="Frames"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Immerse Yourself</h3>
          <a href="https://www.digitalcameraworld.com/features/best-photography-books">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/00ff99/000000.png" title="The best photography books for beginners and pros in 2019" alt="Cameras"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery item">
          <h3>Fall in Love</h3>
          <a href="http://blog.partswarehouse.com/11-of-the-best-diy-books-youll-ever-read/">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/fff700/000000.png" title="11 of the Best DIY Books You’ll Ever Read" alt="Frames"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>&copy; UW-Parkside CSCI 220</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center text vertically and horizontally over the image make the following changes in your css

add `position: relative;` to `.gallery.item`
add new rule

```css
.gallery.item > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```